# TypeError: Cannot set property target of #<Event> which has only a getter Ant Design input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using the **antd input** component with the `allowClear` prop as in the example below:

```
    <Input
      allowClear
      value={value}
      defaultValue={value}
      onChange={e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      placeholder={`Search`}
    />
```

[image]

When you pass the `allowClear` a little *x* button appear in the input so you can clear it, the problem is that every time I click the *x* button I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property target of #<Event> which has only a getter
```

Comment: Show us the onClick function

Comment: Actually i didn't set any onClick function, what I did it's all in the example above

Comment: Ok, show us the Input component

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on code sandbox? I tried it https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-curie-65hecw?file=/src/App.js. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, I just had an old version, updating to the latest one I didn't encounter this problem anymore.